# Tiger Lake Internal Microphone not Detected

Tags: arch-linux, microphone, pipewire, wireplumber

I have problems with the microphone on my Tiger Lake laptop. I have tried to follow the guide on Arch Linux WIKI about configuring Pipewire with wireplumber, and copied the configuration files, but still I can't make my internal microphone work. I lost a couple of hours trying to follow some online tutorials, implementing some fixes, blacklisting devices, etc. to no avail. I am feeling really stuck on this issue, and the lack of a working microphone is a deal breaker for me. I have installed my Arch Linux manually, not using the archinstall script, as it was not working for me and my user is a member of the audio group. Here is some information about my system:

```
# inxi -aA
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel alternate: snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
    bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:a0c8 class-ID: 0401
  API: ALSA v: k6.4.3-arch1-2 status: kernel-api
    tools: alsactl,alsamixer,amixer
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.74 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse
    status: active 2: wireplumber status: active 3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin
    4: pw-jack type: plugin tools: pactl,pw-cat,pw-cli,wpctl
```

```
# wpctl status
PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [0.3.74, gstoyanov@archtop, cookie:1265105126]
 └─ Clients:
        32. pipewire                            [0.3.74, gstoyanov@archtop, pid:4161]
        33. WirePlumber                         [0.3.74, gstoyanov@archtop, pid:4159]
        34. WirePlumber [export]                [0.3.74, gstoyanov@archtop, pid:4159]
        72. wpctl                               [0.3.74, gstoyanov@archtop, pid:4562]

Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      47. Built-in Audio                      [alsa]
 │      65. Pixel Buds Pro             [bluez5]
 │
 ├─ Sinks:
 │      62. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo        [vol: 0.59]
 │  *   66. Pixel Buds Pro             [vol: 0.75]
 │
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │
 ├─ Sources:
 │      30. Undetected Microphone               [vol: 1.00]
 │      63. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo        [vol: 1.00]
 │
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │
 └─ Streams:

Video
 ├─ Devices:
 │      41. HP HD Camera                        [v4l2]
 │      42. HP HD Camera                        [v4l2]
 │      43. HP HD Camera                        [v4l2]
 │      44. HP HD Camera                        [v4l2]
 │      45. HP HD Camera: HP HD Camera          [libcamera]
 │      46. HP HD Camera: HP IR Camera          [libcamera]
 │
 ├─ Sinks:
 │
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │
 ├─ Sources:
 │  *   48. HP HD Camera (V4L2)
 │      50. HP HD Camera (V4L2)
 │      52. Built-in Front Camera
 │      54. Built-in Front Camera
 │
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │
 └─ Streams:

Settings
 └─ Default Configured Node Names:
         1. Audio/Source  alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
```

```
# arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC285 Analog [ALC285 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
[/code]
[code]
# systemctl status --user pipewire-pulse.service pipewire.service wireplumber.service
● pipewire-pulse.service - PipeWire PulseAudio
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire-pulse.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-07-17 09:59:23 CEST; 1min 16s ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire-pulse.socket
   Main PID: 5286 (pipewire-pulse)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 38106)
     Memory: 1.5M
        CPU: 7ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire-pulse.service
             └─5286 /usr/bin/pipewire-pulse

Jul 17 09:59:23 archtop systemd[1305]: Started PipeWire PulseAudio.

● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-07-17 09:59:23 CEST; 1min 16s ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 5281 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 38106)
     Memory: 5.7M
        CPU: 42ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
             └─5281 /usr/bin/pipewire

Jul 17 09:59:23 archtop systemd[1305]: Started PipeWire Multimedia Service.
Jul 17 09:59:23 archtop pipewire[5281]: [0:41:07.821192485] [5281]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:298 libcamera v0.0.5

● wireplumber.service - Multimedia Service Session Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/wireplumber.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-07-17 09:59:23 CEST; 1min 16s ago
   Main PID: 5284 (wireplumber)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 38106)
     Memory: 12.2M
        CPU: 174ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/wireplumber.service
             └─5284 /usr/bin/wireplumber

Jul 17 09:59:23 archtop systemd[1305]: Started Multimedia Service Session Manager.
Jul 17 09:59:23 archtop wireplumber[5284]: [0:41:07.523111539] [5284]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:298 libcamera v0.0.5
Jul 17 09:59:23 archtop wireplumber[5284]: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0x55ced66c3c50> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
Jul 17 09:59:23 archtop wireplumber[5284]: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0x55ced66c3c50> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
Jul 17 09:59:23 archtop wireplumber[5284]: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0x55ced66c3c50> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
Jul 17 09:59:23 archtop wireplumber[5284]: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0x55ced66c3c50> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
Jul 17 09:59:23 archtop wireplumber[5284]: RFCOMM receive command but modem not available: AT+CCWA=1
```

```
# pactl list cards
Card #46
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3
    Driver: alsa
    Owner Module: n/a
    Properties:
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x603f298000 irq 186"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        api.alsa.path = "hw:0"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.alsa.use-ucm = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3"
        device.nick = "HDA Intel PCH"
        device.plugged.usec = "13015928"
        device.product.id = "0xa0c8"
        device.product.name = "Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.vendor.id = "0x8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        media.class = "Audio/Device"
        factory.id = "14"
        client.id = "34"
        object.id = "46"
        object.serial = "46"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x603f298000 irq 186"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.string = "0"
    Profiles:
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5965, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5900, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5765, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5765, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5765, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: no)
        pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 5, sources: 1, priority: 1, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "mic"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                card.profile.port = "0"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra3+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra3+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, availability unknown)
            Properties:
                port.type = "speaker"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
                card.profile.port = "1"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "headphones"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 3"
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
                card.profile.port = "2"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (type: HDMI, priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 4, available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 4"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "3"
                device.product.name = "BenQ XL2430T"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (type: HDMI, priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 5, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 5"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "4"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (type: HDMI, priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 6, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 6"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "5"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (type: HDMI, priority: 5600, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 7, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 7"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "6"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra3, output:hdmi-stereo-extra3+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra3, output:hdmi-surround-extra3+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3+input:analog-stereo

Card #67
    Name: bluez_card.74_74_46_1B_39_F1
    Driver: module-bluez5-device.c
    Owner Module: n/a
    Properties:
        api.bluez5.address = "74:74:46:1B:39:F1"
        api.bluez5.class = "0x240404"
        api.bluez5.connection = "disconnected"
        api.bluez5.device = ""
        api.bluez5.icon = "audio-headset"
        api.bluez5.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_74_74_46_1B_39_F1"
        bluez5.auto-connect = "[ hfp_hf hsp_hs a2dp_sink ]"
        bluez5.profile = "off"
        device.alias = "Pixel Buds Pro"
        device.api = "bluez5"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.description = "Pixel Buds Pro"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.name = "bluez_card.74_74_46_1B_39_F1"
        device.product.id = "0x3004"
        device.string = "74:74:46:1B:39:F1"
        device.vendor.id = "bluetooth:00e0"
        media.class = "Audio/Device"
        factory.id = "14"
        client.id = "34"
        object.id = "62"
        object.serial = "67"
    Profiles:
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        a2dp-sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 16, available: yes)
        headset-head-unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1, available: yes)
        a2dp-sink-sbc: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, codec SBC) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 18, available: yes)
        a2dp-sink-sbc_xq: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, codec SBC-XQ) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 17, available: yes)
        a2dp-sink-aac: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, codec AAC) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 19, available: yes)
        headset-head-unit-cvsd: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP, codec CVSD) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 2, available: yes)
        headset-head-unit-msbc: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP, codec mSBC) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 3, available: yes)
    Active Profile: a2dp-sink-aac
    Ports:
        headset-output: Headset (type: Headset, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "headset"
            Part of profile(s): a2dp-sink, a2dp-sink-sbc, a2dp-sink-sbc_xq, a2dp-sink-aac
        headset-hf-input: Handsfree (type: Headset, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "headset"
            Part of profile(s): headset-head-unit, headset-head-unit-cvsd, headset-head-unit-msbc
        headset-hf-output: Handsfree (type: Headset, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "headset"
            Part of profile(s): headset-head-unit, headset-head-unit-cvsd, headset-head-unit-msbc
```

```
# pactl list sources
Source #59
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: PipeWire
    Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 4294967295
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        alsa.id = "ALC285 Analog"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x603f298000 irq 186"
        alsa.name = "ALC285 Analog"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x603f298000 irq 186"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        api.alsa.path = "front:0"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "0"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "FL,FR"
        card.profile.device = "7"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "monitor"
        device.id = "46"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.routes = "2"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo"
        node.nick = "ALC285 Analog"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:0:front:0:playback"
        priority.driver = "1009"
        priority.session = "1009"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "34"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "merge"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "59"
        object.serial = "59"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "0"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.alsa.use-ucm = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3"
        device.nick = "HDA Intel PCH"
        device.plugged.usec = "13015928"
        device.product.id = "0xa0c8"
        device.product.name = "Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.vendor.id = "0x8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.string = "0"
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #60
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: PipeWire
    Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 4294967295
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        alsa.id = "ALC285 Analog"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x603f298000 irq 186"
        alsa.name = "ALC285 Analog"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x603f298000 irq 186"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        api.alsa.path = "front:0"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "0"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "capture"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "FL,FR"
        card.profile.device = "0"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.id = "46"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.routes = "1"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.source"
        media.class = "Audio/Source"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        node.name = "alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo"
        node.nick = "ALC285 Analog"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:0:front:0:capture"
        priority.driver = "2009"
        priority.session = "2009"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "34"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "split"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "60"
        object.serial = "60"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "0"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.alsa.use-ucm = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3"
        device.nick = "HDA Intel PCH"
        device.plugged.usec = "13015928"
        device.product.id = "0xa0c8"
        device.product.name = "Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.vendor.id = "0x8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.string = "0"
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
    Active Port: analog-input-mic
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #68
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: bluez_output.74_74_46_1B_39_F1.1.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Pixel Buds Pro
    Driver: PipeWire
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 4294967295
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   front-right: 0 /   0% / -inf dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: bluez_output.74_74_46_1B_39_F1.1
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY
    Properties:
        api.bluez5.address = "74:74:46:1B:39:F1"
        api.bluez5.codec = "aac"
        api.bluez5.profile = "a2dp-sink"
        api.bluez5.transport = ""
        card.profile.device = "1"
        device.id = "62"
        device.routes = "1"
        factory.name = "api.bluez5.a2dp.sink"
        device.description = "Pixel Buds Pro"
        node.name = "bluez_output.74_74_46_1B_39_F1.1"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        priority.driver = "1010"
        priority.session = "1010"
        factory.id = "8"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        device.api = "bluez5"
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        media.name = "Pixel Buds Pro"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "merge"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "63"
        object.serial = "68"
        client.id = "34"
        api.bluez5.class = "0x240404"
        api.bluez5.connection = "disconnected"
        api.bluez5.device = ""
        api.bluez5.icon = "audio-headset"
        api.bluez5.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_74_74_46_1B_39_F1"
        bluez5.auto-connect = "[ hfp_hf hsp_hs a2dp_sink ]"
        bluez5.profile = "off"
        device.alias = "Pixel Buds Pro"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.name = "bluez_card.74_74_46_1B_39_F1"
        device.product.id = "0x3004"
        device.string = "74:74:46:1B:39:F1"
        device.vendor.id = "bluetooth:00e0"
        device.class = "monitor"
    Formats:
        pcm
```

Comment: It would be nice to see your messages in dmesg, because it seems the OS is using a legacy driver (Intel PCH) instead of ess8336 (you probably would install the topology file from soc-sof project https://thesofproject.github.io/latest/release.html#source-and-binary-releases ).  I solved by avoiding any module options (like adding quirks to the ess8336 snd_soc_sof_es8336) and choosing "Pro Audio" configuration in PulseAudio Configuration (pavucontrol). It recognizes both speakers (even though the volume is very low) and microphone